# How do I overwrite a macro of a linked table in MS Access using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a split access database. The tables which reside in the backend have "Before Change" macros built into them (in the backend). I need to overwrite these macros with new ones. I have an XML file of the updated macro and am trying to use the code below to overwrite the macros. However, the code below puts the macro on my linked table in the *frontend*. I need the macro to update the macro on the table in the *backend*. Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
LoadFromText acTableDataMacro, "tblEXAMPLE", strXMLpath
```

Comment: This is a one-time event? Go to the backend and run code.

Comment: I would except this is part of an update to a database many people are already using. I need to push the update from a new frontend. I think I found a solution. I will post it soon. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim strXML As String
Dim strXMLpath As String
Dim strBE As String
Dim accessApp As Access.Application

strXML = "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & " encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-16" & Chr(34) & " standalone=" & Chr(34) & "no" & Chr(34) & "?>" & _
"<DataMacros xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application" & Chr(34) & "><DataMacro Event=" & Chr(34) & "BeforeChange" & Chr(34) & "><Statements><ConditionalBlock><If>"

strXMLpath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\XML_File.xml"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strXMLpath)
oFile.WriteLine strXML
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

strBE = CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableName").Connect
strBE = Replace(strBE, ";Database=", "")

Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase strBE, True

accessApp.LoadFromText acTableDataMacro, "TableName", strXMLpath

Kill strXMLpath
```